# Высоко отзываться о ком-то

Tags: фразеология, точное-словоупотребление

Допустимо написать: "Он о нём очень высоко отзывается"? Да, так нередко пишут, но насколько эта фраза грамотна?

"Высоко оценивает" - да.
"Хорошо отзывается" - да.
"Высоко отзывается" - ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но стоит ли?

---

"Высоко оценивает" → "высокая оценка"

"Хорошо отзывается"  → "хороший отзыв"

Есть и ["высокий отзыв"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2&sca_esv=577287814&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKlLEquJ3K7ftsZgCkP5Rf4zVE7BHg:1698444348868&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj33NagnpeCAxWDKxAIHcrGAr8Q_AUoAXoECAMQCw&biw=1920&bih=931&dpr=1), но он плохо трансформируется в высокое отзывание...

В Нацкорпусе нашлось три примера употребления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не-не, Галина, есть ещё достойные примеры: *высоко отзывался* (https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClgqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKJavz9XL%2FdcLQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCLAoqCigKA3JlcRIhCh%2FQstGL0YHQvtC60L4g0L7RgtC30YvQstCw0LvRgdGPMAE%3D).

Comment: Ага, посмотрела. Не понравилось.

Comment: Но ведь можно же, правда? В особом контексте. Ведь нельзя сказать, что фраза неграмотна. P. S.  Здравствуйте-здравствуйте, доброй ночи! Заглядывайте почаще.

Comment: Вопрос: "Допустимо написать?.." Ответ: "Можно, но стоит ли?" Я такого ни за что не напишу.

Comment: Однажды (лет 15 тому) на "Свободе" интервьировался высокий военный чин. Вот чин и говорит: "Армия, с высоты своего амикошонства..." Он не сбился, бодро продолжил, но я настолько офонарела, что слышала только возникшую мёртвую тишину в студии. Никто не прокомментировал, не превратил в шутку, не обыграл. Лучше "Свободы" я не знаю радиостанций.

Comment: Примеров там отнюдь не три, вы просто дали ссылку на последнюю страницу списка примеров. Вот ещё примеры: https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Извините, но я скажу прямо: ваш ответ не является ответом. Вопрос был "насколько такая фраза грамотна?", а вы, скорее, рассказываете о своих личных предпочтениях. Хотелось бы услышать что-то аргументированное, а не "нравится / не нравится".

Comment: Вопрос: "Допустимо написать?" Ответ: "Можно, но стоит ли?" А аргументы - ссылки на прецеденты.

Comment: То, что так писать допустимо, и так очевидно, хотя бы по примерам употребления. Это был скорее риторический оборот, нежели вопрос. Реальный вопрос был о грамотности этой фразы, и ответить на него, похоже, никто не в состоянии.

Comment: Я редактор, а не "нравится / не нравится", в моих текстах не пройдёт.

Comment: Ну, в моих текстах только я решаю, что пройдёт. а что нет, у редактора голос исключительно совещательный. Но это всё неважно - опять же, вопрос был совсем не о редактировании.